# is there any other way to interact with Ethereum's smart contracts via UI besides Etherscan?

Tags: user-interface, ethereum, smartcontracts, metamask, etherscan

I'm aware of Etherscan's capability for interactions with smart contracts on the Ethereum network, but I wonder if there is any other way to read and write from smart contracts.

I'd expect an improved UI/UX usability, allowing input validation, adding documentation on top of the contract etc, yet I couldn't find any other service providing it.

[image: etherscan - smart contract interaction screenshot]

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/otv6lf/is_there_any_other_way_to_interact_with_ethereums/

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://remix.ethereum.org/
There is no service that I know that can provide documentation on top of the contract.

But, it's possible to develop one. Are you interested in how it can be done?

Comment: 1. Yes, I am interested in how it can be done.
2. Do you find any value in another service that will provide enhanced UX for interacting with smart contracts? Basically, I feel Etherscan is doing a nice job and I'm using it quite often but thought it could be nice to provide kind of "postman" API experience on smart contracts. 

wdyt?

Comment: How do you load external deployed contract into REMIX?

Answer (score 0):

The only one I know of is [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.4+commit.c7e474f2.js). This is a great tool for smart contract testing and interaction

And if you are planning to develop your own UI with an API. This is not the exact solution but check out [drizzle](https://www.trufflesuite.com/drizzle). It has some good built in features which will get you started on the front-end parts and showing blockchain data

Comment: How do you load external deployed contract into REMIX?

Answer (score 0):

Both tools presented below load the ABI automatically from the contract address.

## eth95.dev

There is one that looks like old Windows 95 app. Pretty cool.

https://eth95.dev/

[image]

---

## mycrypto.com

https://app.mycrypto.com/interact-with-contracts

[image]